# .NET remove MdiClient Border without using PInvoke methods (.NET native way)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My form is a MdiContainer where i load child forms into.

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is this 3d-style border around the MdiClient.

By using the following method we can remove this effect and also color the area:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
private const int WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x200;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var mdi in this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>())
    {
        mdi.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        mdi.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        int window = GetWindowLong(mdi.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        window &= ~WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
        SetWindowLong(mdi.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, window);
        mdi.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

So it looks like this:

[image]

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish the same result without using the Win32 PInvoke methods and use native .NET methods?

Comment: You'd normally override the CreateParams property getter to tinker with the style flags, you could derive from MdiClient.  But the MdiClient window is automatically created by the container in its [CreateHandle() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,00eb18baaebaca35,references).  Overriding it is quite difficult to do correctly, you cannot call base.CreateHandle().  Even if you attempted it and hack around accessibility restrictions with Reflection, it is never going to look any prettier than what you have now.

Comment: Why do you not want to use P/Invoke? This is what it's designed for, as an escape hatch to do things that are not wrapped by the .NET Framework. Are you trying to run this project on a non-Windows OS or something?

Comment: @HansPassant, I think you meant to write "**if**  you could derive from MdiClient".

Comment: Hmm, true, it is a sealed class.  Well, one more reason it is an idle pursuit.

Comment: Was just wondering if this would be possible at all. Application is targeting windows pure and therefore this was more of a theoretical question.